# Powershell -notin array won't trigger if statement

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement, do-while, jobs

I've recently begun to create a powershell script including a GUI.
To prevent the GUI from freezing I've created a background job in which my function "xyz" runs...
I want to capture a specific window title. If this window closes the if should be fired.

Now my problem with this script is the following:
If I run the script without putting it in the background job it does notice the if statement and returns the value I want to have.

If I run the script and put the task into the background job this job won't stop and won't recognize the if statement.
Does someone have a solution for this problem?

```
Function xyz {
    $global:TitleArray = @("Termius - Hosts","Some Window Title","...")
    $global:WindowClosed = $false
    $global:TitleArray | Out-Host
    $global:Job = start-job -Name FindGame {
        Do {
            (Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""} | Select-Object MainWindowTitle) | % {
                if($_.MainWindowTitle -in $global:TitleArray){
                    $global:WindowFound = $true
                    $global:FoundWindowName = $_.MainWindowTitle
                    do {
                        $WindowArray = @()
                        (Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""} | Select-Object MainWindowTitle) | % {
                           $WindowArray += $_.MainWindowTitle
                        }
                        if($global:FoundWindowName -notin $WindowArray){
                            $global:WindowClosed = $true
                        }
                         Sleep 1
                    } while ($global:WindowClosed -ne $true)
                }

                if($global:WindowClosed){
                    $Global:FoundWindowName | Out-Host
                    exit
                }
                Sleep 1
            }         
        } while ($true)
    }
}

xyz
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PowerShell jobs (of type PSJob) run in a separate process, so they have no access whatsoever to your calling program's environment, not even variables in the Global scope.

To get information *into* the job, you should define a `param()` block in the job's script block, and then use the `-ArgumentList` parameter of `Start-Job` to send in values. Do note that this will be a one time passing in of *values*.

To return data from the job, you just send it out through the pipeline as usual, and to access the data you'll need to use `Get-Job` to determine whether the job "has additional data", and if it does, you use `Receive-Job` to retrieve that data.

Unfortunately all this means that you still need your main thread to be managing the background job, defeating the purpose.

You might [look into `Register-ObjectEvent` instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-6), and pair that with some kind of .Net object that can raise events. It appears that these do run in-process, but more than that, they can fire based on events you might actually be interested in without managing a loop.

So at its simplest, and maybe just to get acquainted you can [look at a timer example where a timer object fires the event on an interval:](https://jrich523.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/creating-a-timer-event-in-powershell/)

```
$timer = new-object timers.timer 

$action = {write-host "Timer Elapse Event: $(get-date -Format ‘HH:mm:ss’)"} 
$timer.Interval = 3000 #3 seconds  

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName elapsed –SourceIdentifier  thetimer -Action $action 

$timer.start()

#to stop run 
$timer.stop() 
#cleanup 
Unregister-Event thetimer
```

But the examples on the Microsoft page even include monitoring a Process Creation Event from WMI, so that and/or and process exit event(?) might be worth looking into.

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks a lot!